# How does the pspicture positioning work in a page?

Tags: pstricks, pspicture

I'm having trouble positioning a `psframe` inside a page with a specific size and it looks like the whole `pspicture` is shifted in the page. This is a MWE of my code

```
\documentclass[border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[paperheight=16cm,paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic,xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(21,16)

\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=black](0,0)(21,16)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, my page is 21cm wide and 16cm tall. My `pspicture` has the coordinates `(0,0)(21,16)` and the `xunit` and `yunit` are set to `1cm`. My `psframe` has the same coordinates as the `pspicture` so what I was expecting once this code is compiled is to have a blue, 16cm x 21cm page with a black frame around it. Instead, what I'm getting is a page with the desired dimensions but the blue background is shifted a bit to the right and up another bit, leaving a white area exposed.

How does `pspicture` positioning work? How can I fix this code? I can manually shift the frame but I would like a more elegant solution because it seems to me that there is something wrong, or perhaps something missing from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `article` and add the following:

- `margin=0pt` for [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) which makes the text block match the paper size;
- `\noindent` before the `pspicture` environment.

  The `pspicture` environment is set like any other textual component (like the letter `a`, or the number `7`. As such, it also is indented with `\parindent` when it starts a paragraph. The width of this "big character" will be `21cm` and have a height of `16cm`, exactly what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[paperheight=16cm,paperwidth=21cm,margin=0pt]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{algebraic,xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}

\noindent
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(21,16)

\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,linewidth=3pt,linecolor=black](0,0)(21,16)

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner. One more thing, if I may... do you know why the standalone class did not work?

Comment: @Gabu: I know [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) has a specific interface dedicated to [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) and [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (supplied during class load: `\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}` or `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`) which might mean its interface with those environments are treated differently to what you think. I don't really use `standalone`, so I'm not that familiar with the inner workings.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use package `geometry` when using `standalone` and run it with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(21,16)   
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!20,linewidth=3pt](0,0)(21,16)   
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]